Getting an Expected "(" or keyword UNNEST but got identifier" when trying to substring in postgres
I'm trying to pull out part of a string so that I can use that as a key to join on for later purposes, but when I try to pull that string out I get the following error:
Message: Syntax error: Expected "(" or keyword UNNEST but got identifier "members_ids" 

The sample data looks like this:
members_ids
PID-160343,DID-28626
PID-142665,DID-1901

My code is pretty simple because I thought it was just a simple substring()
select
    channel_members_ids
    , SUBSTRING(members_ids, 1, POSITION(',' IN members_ids)-1) as patient_id
from `bigquery_production`.my_warehouse.desired_table limit 2

I did try using unnest() but I was getting the same error.
Is there another way I should be doing this? What am I doing wrong?

Does the input actually contain newline characters?

Why is this tagged postgresql and bigquery? They're completely different products...

What datatype is the members_ids column? It looks like a json array to me, as shown in Bigquery?

@MatBailie it's classified as a string in bigquery. And I didn't mean to put postgres in the tags.  forgot to correct it

If you're executing this on BigQuery, there is no POSITION() function. You need to use INSTR().
